# Can nmap cause a dos attack?

Tags: networking, tcp, ports, nmap

Can using this command

```
nmap www.google.com
```

Cause dos attack. It gave me some output but I do not understand it. I have never used nmap before.

Comment: A denial of service attack to who, the website you put in or are you talking about yourself?

Comment: The website I put in. In this case to google

Comment: I am asking if i use the command nmap google.com will i land in trouble

Answer (score 1):

One computer trying to analyze one site is very unlikely to cause a denial of service to happen. You are more likely to run out of resources on your own machine before you put in any kind of dent in a properly set up web server.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is kind of confusing. nmap primarily is a port scanner. It tries to to find open ports on a single or multiple selected targets (in your case www.google.com) by sending a TCP SYN package to every port (of the 1000 most used ports) and checking if an ACK package is received. If an ACK is received the port is considered open. Although port scanning can be regarded kind of malicious when done on a system not owned by you, it is not a dos attack when done once and from a single source system.

Comment: So if i do nmap <target> on a server. Will it harm the target in anyway?

Comment: No, i won't harm the target if there isn't something significantly wrong with it. It can be detected by many firewalls or IDS systems, though.

Comment: Also what do you mean by single source system?

Comment: If you would run this command from thousands of thousands of source systems against the same target simultaneously this might harm the target.